# Django ImproperlyConfigured error with django-admin-csvexport

Tags: python, django, django-admin, uwsgi, python-poetry

So I have been working on adding an admin function to a Django project so that I can export the model instances to csv. It is all working fine locally whilst using Docker. But when deploying it to the server it doesn't work. When I activate the virtualenv (source /home/vfs/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vfs-gOLk6wo--py3.7/bin/activate) and try to import the csvexport module I get this error:
[image]

I've been looking on the internet for quite some time now and can't find a solution. I took over this project and wasn't involved in the server set up or anything. As I'm not that specialized in server side stuff I would appreciate it a lot if someone could help me with this.

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'csvexport',
]
```

model:

```
from csvexport.actions import csvexport
from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin

class FundAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    ...
    actions = [csvexport]
```

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Are you running the shell via Django using the `manage.py shell` management command?

Comment: @IainShelvington When I locate the manage.py file on the server and run the shell (python manage.py shell) I am able to import the package. But in the virtualenv I can't.

Comment: Is there an issue with using the manage.py shell? Django needs to be configured before you can import/use most parts of it, manage.py handles all of this for you but you need to manually call the setup functions if you don't use manage.py. You should most likely be activating your virtualenv before calling manage.py anyway

Comment: @IainShelvington so the steps for deploying changes goes as follows at the moment:
1. git pull
2. install packages via poetry (poetry install)
3. migrate server (poetry run python3 manage.py migrate)
4. reload uwsgi (service uwsgi reload)